# Every ajax query on my website is printing red dot ? what might be wrong?

Tags: php, ajax, drupal, drupal-8

Whenever I'm making an ajax request, I'm getting some red dot on my return.
Here is a sample of the code and the output

I'm using drupal 8.

What am I doing wrong ?

```js
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "/testing-url/get-test",
  method: "POST",
  data: {
    foo: 'bar',
  },
  success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
  },
  error: function () {
    console.log("error");
  }
});
```

And here is the callback of controller

```
 function check_prerequies()
{
   print 'test'; exit;
}
```

[Here is my output from the network tab of the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoiTf.png)

Comment: In good old days I was getting some weird characters at start when I was using UTF8 BOM instead of UTF8 NO-BOM file encoding. That BOM was causing the problem. Check out your script file encoding.

Comment: All my files are actually encoded using UTF8 NO-BOM file encoding

Answer (score 0):

Try to set header for content type and return json. Like this.

```
function check_prerequies()
{
    // create return JSON object
    $resp_obj = new stdClass();
    $resp_obj->test = "test";

    header('Content-Type: application/json'); 

    //response JSON 
    echo json_encode($resp_obj);
    exit(); 
}
```

Comment: I just discovered that even my drupal administration panel has this problem, colud this be a server problem ?

Comment: Maybe, try to make request to public API and see result.

Comment: As you can see on this screenshot, drupal uses json http://i.imgur.com/5bkGUOL.png , but still getting the red dots.

Comment: I tried a public request and I'm getting a clean result, thank you. But I still cannot figure out what is the problem with my drupal installation.

Comment: Make request to script witout ajax and see result will have dots.